# can find a suit value to declare my constructor

Tags: android, json, flutter, api, dart

`class Space{`
`List? photos;`
`}`

`Space({`
`this.photos=[],` //The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Space({ this.photos = const []})
```

It should works :)